# How can I output a big squared image for Facebook shared page URL?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I stumbled on a FB page that has all the posts which are from URLs from their site, display big squared images instead of the default cropped horizontal rectangle.

[image]

### When I share the same URL at any page this is the output

[image]

Their site uses Magento CMS.

### How are they achieving this result?

I tried all the FB publishing tools to no avail.

- Is it a browser plugin?
- Is it a javascript that alters FB scrape bot behavior?